# How do you find the first m twin primes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

My program is supposed to find the first m twin primes and print that they are.

```
def isItPrime(n):
    tests = primes.copy()
    while len(tests) != 0:
    if n % tests[-1] == 0:
     return False
elif n % tests[-1] != 0:
    tests.pop()
  if len(tests) == 0:
    primes.append(n)
    return True
def findTwinPrimes(a , b): 
  if isItPrime(a) == True:
    if isItPrime(b) == True:
      if b - a == 2:
        print(a, "-", b, "is a twin prime")
def firstMTwinPrimes(m):
  o = 0
  i = 1
  if o < m :
   print(i)
   k = 3
   l = 5
   findTwinPrimes(k,l)
   k += 1
   l += 1
   o += 1
firstMTwinPrimes(7)
```

Currently, it runs without errors but also does not work. The i is to check how many times the program runs and it only runs once. I do not know why becuase if o is less than m it should run again. Also for 3 and 5, they are twin primes but it doesn't work for them. isItPrime is already implemented to check if a number is prime or not. It returns the answer.

Comment: you're code worked for me when I used my own isItPrime function, I think the problem is in your `isItPrime` function.

Comment: Except for {3, 5} all twin prime pairs are of the form {6n-1, 6n+1}, such as {5, 7} or {29, 31}.  That will help speed up your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JayMody notes, your `isItPrime()` is broken.  We can make it work as intended, but the way it relies on being called with increasing arguments, and its use of a global primes list, are problems.  (I.e. consider first calling `isItPrime(22)` followed by `isItPrime(6)`)

@JohanC's answer, which you accepted, doesn't maintain a global prime list, instead doing more divisions than necessary by testing all numbers from 2 to the number. This is far less efficient than what you were attempting to implement.  I think we can salvage your original intent, and not expose a non-general `isItPrime()` test, by making one function internal to the other:

```
def firstMTwinPrimes(m):
    primes = [2]

    def isItPrime(n):
        for prime in primes:
            if prime * prime > n:
                break

            if n % prime == 0:
                return False

        primes.append(n)

        return True

    number = 3
    count = 0

    while count < m:
        for n in range(number, number + 3, 2):

            if n == primes[-1]:
                continue

            if not isItPrime(n):
                break

        else:  # no break
            print(number, "-", number + 2, "are twin primes")
            count += 1

        number += 2
```

We have to be careful not to add a prime to the list twice when it's tested as a lower and upper number.  You'll find this approach is a couple of orders of magnitude faster than @JohanC's answer when `M` exceeds a hundred.  You were on the right track.

The sieve-based solution @AlokMishra posted is faster still, but it is designed to find all pairs up to some number, not some number of pairs as you specified.

Comment: My code was not intended to be fast, only to be as close as possible to the question, so OP could compare their code and see where to improve. Of course many optimizations are possible, but that would part from the idea to have an as simple as possible code that just works. For example, you could easily go in steps of 6 instead of 2. Apart from the prime 3, all first primes of a twin prime are necessarily 5 modulo 6.

Answer (score 2):

please, post your code with function and error

otherwise, try this:

```
def printTwinPrime(n): 

    prime = [True for i in range(n + 2)] 
    p = 2

    while (p * p <= n + 1): 

        # If prime[p] is not changed,  
        # then it is a prime 
        if (prime[p] == True): 

            # Update all multiples of p 
            for i in range(p * 2, n + 2, p): 
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1

    # check twin prime numbers 
    # display the twin prime numbers 
    for p in range(2, n-1): 
        if prime[p] and prime[p + 2]: 
            print("(",p,",", (p + 2), ")" ,end='') 


# driver program 
if __name__=='__main__': 

    # static input 
    n = 7

    # Calling the function 
    printTwinPrime(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- You need to change your `if o < m` to a while loop: `while o < m`. With only the if-test, `findTwinPrimes` is only called once. You need to call it again and again until you have enough twin primes. Inside that while-loop, you need to increment `o` only when you really found twin primes. Therefore, `findTwinPrimes` should return True when it found a twin prime, and False when it didn't. Also, `k=3; l=5` should be put before the start of the while-loop, so they can be incremented inside the loop.
- Instead of `if isItPrime(a) == True:` it is better to just write `if isItPrime(a):`. That has the same effect and is more readable.
- You have a variable `i` that you just give a value of `1` and print, but don't do anything useful with. You can leave it out.
- Python code is more readable if you indent with four spaces instead of only 2

Here is the adapted code:

```py
def isItPrime(p):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def findTwinPrimes(a, b):
    if isItPrime(a):
        if isItPrime(b):
            if b - a == 2:
                print(a, "-", b, "is a twin prime")
                return True
    return False

def firstMTwinPrimes(m):
    o = 0
    k = 3
    l = 5
    while o < m:
        if findTwinPrimes(k, l):
            o += 1
        k += 1
        l += 1

firstMTwinPrimes(7)
```

Output:

```
3 - 5 is a twin prime
5 - 7 is a twin prime
11 - 13 is a twin prime
17 - 19 is a twin prime
29 - 31 is a twin prime
41 - 43 is a twin prime
59 - 61 is a twin prime
```

PS: If you want, you can write

```
    if isItPrime(a):
        if isItPrime(b):
            if b - a == 2:
```

as

```
    if isItPrime(a) and isItPrime(b) and b - a == 2:
```